# Why does parallel source function watermark forward works with rebalance

Tags: apache-flink

I have following flink code to exercise the watermark behavior with parallel source function. I defined a parallel source function but ony the first partition will have data.

Because the watermark is using the minimum value of watermarks of upstream, so that,there is no watermark forwards because the source function has 2 partitions don't produce data, it is expected that there is no output on the console.

Then I add `rebalance` before `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` as the code shows, when I rerun the application, I find that the watermark forwards successfully, and there are output on the console.

I would ask why `rebalance` works here that the watermark can be forwarded, thanks!

```
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.{RichParallelSourceFunction, SourceFunction}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.watermark.Watermark
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

case class MyOrder(name: String, create_date: String)

class MyParallelOrderSourceFunction extends RichParallelSourceFunction[MyOrder] {
  val data = ParallelSourceFunctionWatermarkTest.createData()

  override def run(ctx: SourceFunction.SourceContext[MyOrder]): Unit = {
    val idx = getRuntimeContext.getIndexOfThisSubtask
    //Only the first subTask/partition will have data
    if (idx == 0) {
      data.map(e => MyOrder(e._1, e._2)).foreach(ctx.collect)
    }
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

  override def cancel(): Unit = {
  }
}

object ParallelSourceFunctionWatermarkTest {
  def to_milli(str: String) =
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(str).getTime

  def to_char(milli: Long) = {
    val date = if (milli <= 0) new Date(0) else new Date(milli)
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date)
  }

  def createData(): Seq[(String, String)] = {
    //create 100 records, create_date increase by 1 second for each record
    var time = "2023-02-26 17:26:11"
    (1 to 100).map {
      _ =>
        time = to_char(to_milli(time) + 1000)
        ("A", time)
    }
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration())

    //MyParallelOrderSourceFunction's parallelism is 3
    //call rebalance before assignTimestampsAndWatermarks, water mark forwards； if doesn't call rebalance, then no water mark forwards
    env.addSource(new MyParallelOrderSourceFunction).setParallelism(3).rebalance/*rebalance method call makes watermark forward works*/.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks[MyOrder] {

      private var max_seen: Long = Long.MinValue
      private val allowLateness = 4000

      override def checkAndGetNextWatermark(lastElement: MyOrder, extractedTimestamp: Long): Watermark = {
        if (extractedTimestamp > max_seen) {
          max_seen = extractedTimestamp
        }
        new Watermark(max_seen - allowLateness)
      }

      override def extractTimestamp(element: MyOrder, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
        to_milli(element.create_date)
      }
    }).keyBy(_.name.hashCode % 3).timeWindow(Time.of(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).process(new ProcessWindowFunction[MyOrder, String, Int, TimeWindow] {
      override def process(key: Int, cxt: Context, elements: Iterable[MyOrder], out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
        val ws = to_char(cxt.window.getStart)
        val we = to_char(cxt.window.getEnd)
        val sb = new StringBuilder()

        sb.append(s"($ws, $we), ${elements.map(e => (e.name, e.create_date)).mkString(",")}")
        out.collect(sb.toString())
      }
    }).setParallelism(3).print()

    env.execute()
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `.keyBy()`, the watermarks are multiplexed across all of the downstream subtasks. So if any of the source sub-tasks generate a watermark, that watermark will be sent to all of the downstream `.timeWindow()/.process()` sub-tasks.